# Calculating distance between a Point and a MultiPolygon PostGIS object

Tags: python, postgis, sql, django, st-distance

I'm working in a layer with MultiPolygons and I'm trying to calculate the shortest distance between a MultiPolygon and a point which is contained in that MultiPolygon, using Django and PostGIS.

At first I check which MultiPolygon contains that Point and I store it in a variable:

```
mpoly = MPoly.objects.filter(geom__contains=location)
```

Then, I'm trying to calculate the distance between the point and the mpoly object using the psycopg2 interface:

```
curs.execute("SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText(%s), ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;Point(24.050, 35.311)')) FROM MPoly" % mpoly)
```

But it raises the following syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ";"
   LINE 1: SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText(SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON ((23.567..
```

I think that the error comes from "mpoly"'s format but why ? If I type in a Python interpreter >> mpoly, it prints: MultiPolygon object at 0x7fc8d5130

Comment: Look at the docs for [ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html). There is no form with a semicolon. Either use the correct form, or wrap geomfromtext in ST_SetSrid call.

Comment: I do not agree with you [@John Powell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/429/john-powell-aka-bar%C3%A7a), because [this source](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeogFromText.html) shows that the semicolon is not an issue. I think [@Gpetr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/26489/gpetr) should try this code with `ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(24.050, 35.311)')`. I think the issue is about **POINT** instead of **Point**.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your quick responses. I think that the problem is that the system interprets mpoly variable with this format (SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON ((23.567...) automatically. Which is not an acceptable format from ST_Distance function but I don't know how to define the format in an acceptable way.

Comment: @Taras, you are correct, I misread it. Apologies.

Comment: I think it is because you need to enclose the text string you are sending to ST_GeogFromText in quotes, so you have SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('%s') or something similar.

Comment: [@John Powell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/429/john-powell-aka-bar%C3%A7a) maybe you are right. Perhaps, `mpoly` could not find its string-place.

Comment: You have written faulty WKT. There should not be a comma between the coordinates, like in here `select ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(24.050 35.311)')`.

Comment: @John Powell I checked that syntax (SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('%s') and it raises the following error: "InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" . I think that this error is closer to the solution.

Comment: @user30184 you are right, but the error remains the same in both cases : with quotes on %s or without.

Comment: Perhaps drop the 4326; part, as geog is assumed to be 4326? Or, use ST_SetSRID(ST_GeogFromText(''), 4326), if it is indeed the semi colon that is the  issue.

Comment: Do you really have WKT in mpoly, or is it perhaps already either geometry or geography in the table?

Comment: The query is using ST_Geo**g**FromText, while the error message talks about ST_Geo**m**FromText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the helpfull answer of @yorkie I'd like to post a complete solution of my issue about calculating of distance between a MultiPolygon object and a Point. The answer covers the case that the MultiPolygon object contains that point.

At first, I converted the MultiPolygon geometry to MultiLineString because if MultiPolygon contains the point the distance will be zero (0.0).

```
curs.execute("SELECT ST_Boundary('%s')::geometry(MULTILINESTRING,4326)" % poly[0].geom)
```

After that, I converted the above MultiLineString geometry to Well Known Text.

```
curs.execute("SELECT ST_AsEWKT('%s')" % curs.fetchone())
```

and I stored the result in a variable:

```
t = curs.fetchone()
```

and finally, I calculated the distance:

```
curs.execute("select st_distance(st_geogfromtext('%s'),st_geogfromtext('srid=4326;point(24.050 35.311)'))" % t)
```

Answer (score 1):

a research on the topic of [WKT-Geometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) and the syntax of [st_geogfromtext](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeogFromText.html) reveals, that your query should look something like this:

```
select st_distance(st_geogfromtext('srid=4326;multipolygon (((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20)),((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5)))'),st_geogfromtext('srid=4326;point(40 20)'));
   st_distance   
-----------------
 892746.97610591
```

Your mistake was to type point(40 **,** 20), not point(40 20). Note that the single quotes are obligatory if you use the st_geogfromtext function, whereas case sensitivity is not a deal. Thus, maybe you could also try quoting your %s, as [John Powell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/429/john-powell-aka-bar%c3%a7a) already indicated.

Furthermore, are you really sure to want to calculate the shortest distance of a point being within a multipolygon? Because, if the multipolygon contains the point, the distance from the point to the multipolygon is 0 by defintion. See for example this query, where a point lies within the boundaries of the multipolygon:

```
select st_distance(st_geogfromtext('srid=4326;multipolygon (((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20)),((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5)))'),st_geogfromtext('srid=4326;point(20 12)'));
 st_distance 
-------------
           0
```

If you really want to have the distance from the point to the boundaries of the multipolygon, you could try to convert the multipolygon to a multilinestring or similar.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer ! Your answer and the comments above helped me to find the issue. There were two syntax errors. The one is that I had to enclose "mpoly" variable into quotes and the other is that there should not be commas between Point's coordinates (Point(24.050 35.311)). Also you are right that the distance should be 0 because the point is contained to the multipolygon but at first, I have to find from the database which is the polygon that contains the point. Thus I have to use Polygon geometry.

Comment: Also I had to drop "from MPoly" from my command. Finally the command that did the job is: curs.execute("select st_distance(st_geogfromtext('%s'),st_geogfromtext('srid=4326;point(24.050 35.311)'))" % poly.geom)